# Append result in array

Tags: arrays, for-loop

How can I calculate the result according to the "1" or "0".

If the second column shows 0, I want the result to remain 0, and if the second column shows 1, the number `result = (185.244324/187.300232)` will be saved in the c=[] array.

```
array([[187.300232, '0'],
       [185.244324, '1'],
       [185.427719, '0'],
       [186.923798, '0'],
       [182.26181, '1'],
       [185.253952, '1'],
       [181.277283, '0'],
       [181.518585, '0'],
       [179.192429, '0'],
       [180.19624299999998, '1'],
       [183.89300500000002, '1'],
       [181.11319, '1'],
       [183.584122, '0'],]
```

The codes presented below.

```
n= -1
c = []
for i in range(len(b)) :
    if  df2[n:n+1,1:3] == 1: 
        n += 1 
        result = (df2[n:n+1,0:1] / df2[n+1:n+2,0:1] )
        c.append(result)
    else :
        c.append(0)
c
```